# Classic ASP - set cookies in addition to session

Tags: session, asp-classic

I'm trying to track user activity in my system up to the point where session expires- if they request a page, the session is missing but so is their user information.

I have too many pages to pass any kind of session id along the querystring, so I thought maybe in one of my top includes I could set a cookie that doesn't expire with session, and reset it at each login. This way I can track the users/pages.

Is this okay to do along with session vars? How would I do this?

Comment: Eduardo pretty much covered it but you can find out a little more here: http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_cookies.asp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use cookies, because if you use session it would expire also

**To set the cookie**

```
Response.Cookies("TrackID") = 'Something'
Response.Cookies("TrackID").expires = DateAdd( "yyyy", 5, Date )
```

**To get the cookie**

```
TrackID = Request.Cookies("TrackID")
```

Comment: @csharpbd: This is classic ASP.

Comment: Yes, I know. I try this in Classic ASP but it's not working. Response.Cookies ("MyCookie")="Hello World!"
Response.Cookies("MyCookie").Expires = "12/31/2022"
Response.Write Request.Cookies("MyCookie")

Comment: try flushing the response and request aren't populated at the same time. you send the cookie to the page via response, then after the next request comes in you read the cookie via request. You can't do it all on one page / request.